# InnerHTML remains the same regardless of conditional statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an HTML span tag to display some text if a certain radio option is chosen. If I click on the 2nd radio option, the span tag text should be overridden and turned into an empty string. The text currently does not disappear.

I have tried the style.display = "none" and I have also tried overriding the innerHTML with an empty string.

Javascript

```
        if(timeCard[1].value == "N/A"){

            document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "Please verify this field before submitting.";
            console.log('Hi');
        }else{
            document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="timecard" value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="timecard" value="N/A">N/A<br>
<span id="radioError" style="font-size: 0.9em; color:red;"></span>
```

I want the span text to be overridden by the 2nd innerHTML in the javascript.

Comment: There is a lot you are not showing. How are you getting and testing the current radio option that has been selected? What does objPayCode and timeCard have to do with this?

Comment: your problem should how you check the radio box value. Please edit you question with the code about radio buttonl

Comment: I have posted the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `timeCard` is an array, instead of `timeCard[1].value`, you're just looking to check that `timeCard[1]` is equal to `N/A`.

```js
timeCard = ["one", "N/A"];

if (timeCard[1] == "N/A") {
  document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "Please verify this field before submitting.";
} else {
  document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "Please mitting.";
}
```

```html
<span id="radioError" style="font-size: 0.9em; color:red;"></span>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code but the Please Verify... font stays on the screen even when I click the other radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Without complete code, at a guess, you should be using .checked property to see if it is selected instead of value given that value for timeCard[1] will always be "N/A".

```
if (timeCard[1].checked) {
   document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "Please verify this field before submitting.";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("radioError").innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct way to check which radio button is checked.